How do you get Google Sheets pivot tables to count categorical values for each column of your sheet?
I want to know how many of each categorical value is found in each column. The first column lists possible colors (what I'm counting). The other three columns list the name of a person who has made 4 color choices, so there's 4 color names under each person. I want my pivot table to tell me how many times each person choose each color. What I've tried doesn't count them correctly.

I used the 1st column in the sheet, that lists the possible colors, for the Rows in the pivot table & the row header (person's name) in the sheet for the Values in the pivot table & summarized them with COUNTA. The count is way off.

If you are interested to go with formula, then could try-
=QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(B1:D1&"|"&B2:D5),"|")),"select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1 format count(Col2) '0'")



If you want 0 instead of null then try =MAP(QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(TOCOL(B1:D1&"|"&B2:D5),"|")),"select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1 format count(Col2) '0'"),LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",0,x))).

Is it possible to this with a pivot table without writing extra functions? Could I have laid out the sheet in a better way for that?

Alternative Answer using Array Formula
You can use this formula to count how many times each color appears in the lists for Bill, John, and Bruce.
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",, SPLIT(LAMBDA(colors, COUNTIF(B$2:B$5, colors) & "|" & COUNTIF(C$2:C$5, colors) & "|" & COUNTIF(D$2:D$5, colors))(G2:G), "|")))

The SPLIT function breaks the string into separate counts for easy display. By using the ARRAYFORMULA function it will automatically apply to every cell in column H, I and J. This means you don't have to manually copy and paste the formula to each cell, and you can see the results for all entries at once.
Sample Output:

Reference:
Google Sheets function list
Update: To do it with a pivot table without writing extra functions
Instead of listing colors in one column and each person’s choices in separate columns, it's more efficient to organize your data in a "long format." This means you'll list each person's color choices one after another in a single column.
Here’s how you can structure your data:

In the pivot table, put colors in rows, person in columns (uncheck the show totals), and  person in values using COUNTA.
Sample Output:


Is it possible to this with a pivot table without writing extra functions? Could I have laid out the sheet in a better way for that?

I updated my answer about your comment.

Oh I see. Thank you. Oh but then I loose the easier to see info on what was each person's 1st choice, 2nd choice, etc as choice sequence may be of interest for this data.

I believe this is a different question, as your main inquiry is about how to count the number of times each person chooses a particular color. You may want to post another question regarding the ranking of each person's first choice, 2nd choice, etc.
